# After searching, the edit item takes previous value, whats wrong?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I have done a dataTableFilter to create edit and delete items with search. Everything works fine until I do "Search as you Type", but when I add an item after doing a "Search as you type", the item is added in the database and the view, but if I click edit aginst it, it shows the values below it and when I press cancel, the added value disappears ! Again if I do search as you type the new item starts appearing.

I have been struggling with this for long, are there limitations in JSF primefaces ?

```
    <p:dataTable id="itemTable" var="row"
                value="#{itemBean.allitems}"
                emptyMessage=" No itemue found" styleClass="borderless"
                paginator="true" rows="10" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                style="font-family:'Lato';font-size:12px;border:1px solid #d7d9b2"
                widgetVar="cataTable"
                filteredValue="#{itemBean.filtereditems}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <p:outputPanel>
                            <div class="col-lg-9"
                                style="margin-top: 6px; text-align: right; font-weight: bold">
                                <h:outputText value="Search all fields : " />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                <p:inputText id="globalFilter"
                                    onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {return false; }"
                                    onkeyup="PF('cataTable').filter()"
                                    styleClass="form-control txtFieldInput"
                                    placeholder="Enter keyword" />
                            </div>
                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </div>
                </f:facet>
                <p:column headerText="itemue Name" filterBy="#{row.name}"
                    filterStyle="display:none" sortBy="name" filterMatchMode="contains"
                    style="width:8%;text-align: center">
                    <h:outputText value="#{row.name}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="No.of subitems"
                    style="width:8%;text-align: center">
                    <h:outputText value="#{row.totalsubitems}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Description"
                    style="width:8%;text-align: center">
                    <h:outputText value="#{row.description}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Date(MM/DD/YYYY)"
                    style="width:8%;text-align: center">
                    <h:outputText value="#{row.toDate}">
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Base URL" style="width:8%;text-align: center">
                    <h:outputText value="#{row.itemurl}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:5%;text-align: center">
                    <f:facet name="header">Action</f:facet>
                    <p:commandButton ajax="true" icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="Edit"
                        update=":itemForm:updateitemData"  
                        oncomplete="PF('updateitem').show()">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{row}"
                            target="#{itemBean.selecteditem}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton ajax="true" icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Deactive"
                        style="background-color:green" rendered="#{row.isActive == 'Yes'}"
                        actionListener="#{itemBean.deleteitem(row)}"
                        oncomplete="PF('itemDelete').show()">
                    </p:commandButton>

                    <p:commandButton ajax="true" icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Active"
                        style="background-color:red" rendered="#{row.isActive == 'No'}"
                        actionListener="#{itemBean.activateitem(row)}"
                        oncomplete="PF('activateitem').show()">
                    </p:commandButton>

                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: 1: [mcve], 2: version info please, 3: filtering om each keyup without delay is not best practice.

Comment: primefaces 6.0, JSF 2.2.13

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering 1 out of 3... suggestion (as you should sort of already have done with your [mcve] is to try 6.1, 6.2 and 7.0 and please also do try 3

Comment: search any data in the filter than clear the filter, Now  we try to edit the row which is picking up the previous record but not the newly added record.

Comment: Thank you for adding comment and also addressing 1 and 3 from the first comment